# How to move one row down by one automatically on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make it so that way the total of the amount made will move one row down every time a new row has been filled in above it but i cant find the formula. i have it so it will auto calculate the profits but i dont want to have the total so far down that we have to search for it every time

I have looked for a long while on google and youtube but found nothing

Comment: Use `VSTACK()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try `VSTACK()` like-

```
=VSTACK(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),SUM(A2:A))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Apps Script!

Click on **Extensions** > **Apps Script**.

Delete any code that's in the editor and paste the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = e.range;
  
  // Check if the edited cell is in column B and not in the first row
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == 2 && editedCell.getRow() > 1) {
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + lastRow);
    var totalFormula = "=SUM($B$3:B" + lastRow + ")";
    range.setFormula(totalFormula);
  }
}
```

The script will now calculate the running total formula every time you modify a cell in column B (at the start with row 2) to include all values from row 3 to the final full row in column B.